# Platform Glitch AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a Pokemon-themed game, which will have various mini-games within it. The 1st scene requires that the character jump on two platforms, one on the right and one higher up on the left, in order to reach a Pokeball, which triggers one of the mini-games.

The character jumps correctly and lands on the platform without a problem; however, whenever I try and jump directly underneath a platform, the character gets stuck. He can move, but his head is stuck to the bottom (imagine him sliding along the side). The odd thing is that once his head is no longer underneath said platform, he performs a jump motion. I also found that pressing the jump key repeatedly forces the character through and out of the platform.

Attached is the code I have so far:

```
    var gravity:Number = 10;  
    var jumpPower:Number = 0;  
    var isJumping:Boolean = false; 
    var checkCollision:Boolean = false;
    var checkJump:Boolean = false;
    var ground:Number = 393 - trainer.height;
    var isRight = false;
    var checkUnder:Boolean = false;
    var isLeft = false;

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,released);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,pressed);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, doJump);  
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ballHit);

    //MOVING LEFT OR RIGHT CODE-----------------------------------------------------------
    function released(event:KeyboardEvent){
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            isRight = false;
            }
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            isLeft = false;
            }
        }

    function pressed(event:KeyboardEvent){
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            isRight = true;
            }
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            isLeft = true;
            }
        }

    function loop(e:Event){
        if(isRight){
            trainer.x += 10;
            }
        if(isLeft){
            trainer.x -= 10;
            }
        //trainer hits walls
        if(trainer.x >= 500){
            trainer.x = 500;
            }
        if(trainer.x <=0){
            trainer.x = 0;
            }
        if(trainer.y <= 0){
            trainer.y = 0;
            }
        }
    // END OF MOVING LEFT OR RIGHT CODE-----------------------------------------------------------

    //JUMP WITH GRAVITY CODE----------------------------------------------------------------------
    function doJump(event:KeyboardEvent):void  
    {  

       if(isJumping == false){
       if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)  
        {  
            jumpPower = -35;
    isJumping = true;
}          
}  
    }  

    function update(evt:Event):void  
    {  
        if(isJumping == true)  
        {  
            trainer.y += jumpPower;  
            jumpPower += 5;  }
        if(trainer.y >= 300)
        {    
            isJumping = false; 
        }
        //character lands on platform
        else if(trainer.y + 65 >= platformOne.y && trainer.x >=  platformOne.x - 60 && trainer.hitTestObject(platformOne)){
            isJumping = false;
        }
        else if(trainer.y + 65 >= platformTwo.y && trainer.x <=  platformTwo.x + 250 && trainer.hitTestObject(platformTwo)){
            isJumping = false;
            }

        else{
            isJumping = true;
            }
        /*if(trainer.y > platformOne.y && trainer.x >  platformOne.x && trainer.hitTestObject(platformOne)){
            trace("test");
            }*/
    }  
    //END OF JUMP WITH GRAVITY CODE--------------------------------------------------------------

    //CHECK BALL HIT CODE------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function ballHit(checkCol:Event):void{
     if(trainer.hitTestObject(pokeballOne)){
         pokeballOne.visible = false;
         checkCollision = true;
         }
        if(checkCollision == true){
            pokeBallOpenOne.y = 33.3;
            pokeBallOpenOne.x = 30.9;
            btnChallenge1.y = 58.3;
            btnChallenge1.x = 8.9;
            }
    }
    //END OF CHECK BALL HIT CODE----------------------------------------------------------------

    //CLICKING THE CHALLENGE BUTTON-------------------------------------------------------------
    btnChallenge1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handleClick3);

    function handleClick3(pEvent:MouseEvent){
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ballHit);
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
        gotoAndPlay("shootingStart", "Scene 4" );
    }
    //END OF CLICK THE CHALLEGNE BUTTON---------------------------------------------------------
```

So, the issues I would like to have fixed are:

1. How do I prevent the character from being stuck to the platform?
2. How do I prevent the character from performing a jump motion after he is no longer under a platform?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that you have `isJumping` and `jumpPower` both in charge of two things at once:

`isJumping` controls whether the player can jump *and* whether the player's jump movement is applied.
`jumpPower` controls the player's jump movement *and* makes them fall as if due to gravity.

There might be a clever way to get that all to work, but I personally find it easier to have separate `gravity`, `isJumping` and `jumpPower` variables.

It looks like you already have a `gravity` variable at the top, but it doesn't seem to get used anywhere else, so I would suggest:

- Using "speed" variables for the player that get added to their position every update.
- Adding `gravity` to the player's y speed every update if `isJumping` is true.
- Either swapping the `isJumping` check in `update` for `if (jumpPower < 0)`, or just adding the jump power to the player's y speed straight away when the keyboard is pressed instead.
- Checking the player's y speed on the platform collision, then if they're moving down set `isJumping` to false, but if they're moving up set `jumpPower` and their y speed to `0`.